# How to make TypeScript generate a CommonJS valid module?

Tags: typescript, commonjs

Let's say I have a module in TypeScript:

```
export default function myModule(name: string): void {
  alert(`Hello, ${name}!`)
}
```

When I run `tsc` to build the above code, and try to import the generated code through Node.js (pure JavaScript):

```
const myModule = require('./dist/myModule.js')
myModule('Luiz') // ERROR! `myModule` is `undefined`
```

The only way to make it work is by using `.default`  after the `require()`, which is not what I want:

```
//                                            ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
const myModule = require('./dist/myModule.js').default
myModule('Luiz') // Now it works.
```

How can I make TypeScript generate an output that I can use later as a Node.js module (as I'm publishing the package into NPM) without that `.default` property? Just like this:

```
const myModule = require('my-module')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Use `export =` to build a CommonJS module that exports a function.

The [TypeScript docs say](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require):

> TypeScript supports `export =` to model the traditional CommonJS and AMD workflow... The `export =` syntax specifies a single object that is exported from the module. This can be a class, interface, namespace, function, or enum.

#### Full Setup

myModule.ts

```js
export = function myModule(name: string): void {
  console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`)
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

myModule.js (output)

```
"use strict";
module.exports = function myModule(name) {
    console.log("Hello, " + name + "!");
};
```

demo.js (usage)

```
const myModule = require('./my-module');

myModule('Luiz'); // Hello, Luiz!
```

Comment: why tsc can not convert "export default" to "export =" ? It is weird.

Comment: They're not the same