# not able to require default exported function from typescript file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, typescript, commonjs

I am trying to build an npm package in typescript.
I am not able to require and use the default function exported in the typescript module. I have tried changing module options in `tsconfig.json` to `UMD` and `AMD`, but no luck.

```
//index.ts
export default function () {
  console.log("greet");
}

export function greet2() {
  console.log("greet2");
}
```

```
//tsconfig.json
{

  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonJS",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

```
//index.js
const greet = require("./lib/index");

greet();

greet.greet2();
```

```
//console
greet();
^

TypeError: greet is not a function
```

Webpack can be used for the solution, But I would like to know if there is any way I can do without using Webpack.

Comment: Your webpack compiles all js files to minified bundle file. Separate files like `index.js` not directly are added to this file. They could have a bit different names with system prefixes that are got from webpack object. It means your ts module is encapsulated inside   package object and supposing to use only inside this namespace.

Comment: I am sorry I am not using webpack right now, I would like to know if there is any solution with just tsc and without using webpack.

Comment: in this cases you need additional libraries for reading `require` methods  and manually add all compiled js scripts to your web page. It is a bit complicated and unusual way but sometimes might be useful.

Comment: guess I will need webpack then. Thank you. 
I did find a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402067/how-to-make-typescript-generate-a-commonjs-valid-module But if I do it this way, I won't be able to do named exports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing module syntax. When you use require, you are going to get back an object with a `default` property, and a `greet2` property.

`require` assumes you know how your exports are structured, because they can be in just about any shape you specified with `module.exports = anything` ES Modules on the other hand have a strict specification. This allows the an import to assume the shape of what comes from an export and do things like conveniently destructuring it for you.

Currently if you log it, the greet variable will be an object like so:

```
Object {default: function _default(), greet2: function greet2()}
```

This of course is not a function and thus the error.

If instead you use import syntax

```
import greet from './lib/index';
```

it will compile to something equivalent to:

```
const greet = require('./lib/index').default;
```

You are of course able to use require yourself in this same fashion, you just have to be aware of the shape of whatever is returned from `require` and destructure it accordingly.