# dateFormat is not a function

Tags: node.js

I am a newbie at coding i have checked to see if i can find what is wrong on stackoverflow and googled still cant sort the error,  dateFormat is not a function, i a running node_modules "dateformat": "^5.0.1",  using "node": ">=10.23.0" on ubuntu 18.04 bionic

I don't have type: module in packages.json,  I have tried renaming dateformat.js to .cjs  I have removed require and added import to js files and now get this error:

> TypeError: dateFormat is not a function
> exceptionWriter.js:19
>
> ```
> var time = dateFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss');
> ```

Changed dateFormat  to dateString and now no difference.
this is trying to build
dvandal
/
cryptonote-nodejs-pool  no answer from dev on this

this is file code

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var cluster = require('cluster');

var dateFormat = import('dateformat');

/**
 * Handle exceptions
 **/
module.exports = function(logSystem) {
  process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {

    console.log('\n' + err.stack + '\n');

    var time = dateFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss');
    fs.appendFile(config.logging.files.directory + '/' + logSystem + '_crash.log', time +
      '\n' + err.stack + '\n\n',
      function(err) {
        if (cluster.isWorker)
          process.exit();
      });
  });
};
```

Hope I have set this out right on stack any help you could give me would be most welcome

Comment: Maybe change `import('dateformat');` to `require('dateformat');`. If you need it to be dynamic, use the Promise

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply  i already had   require('dateformat'); and changed to import

Comment: Why did you change it to `import()`?

Comment: when building it gave me esm module required  error  i changed require to import etc as suggested by the log console error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [not able to require default exported function from typescript file in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577733/not-able-to-require-default-exported-function-from-typescript-file-in-nodejs)

Comment: I looked at this phil but I am not using typescript

Comment: As an update this is the build https://github.com/dvandal/cryptonote-nodejs-pool  i checked to make sure there is no typescript only javascript

Comment: @dagwood I didn't ask if it was the same as your question, I asked if it answered it. AKA have you tried `var dateFormat = require('dateformat').default`?

Comment: sorry Phil didn't realise that yes i have added this to the file but it gives me the same error that i started with  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
exceptionWriter.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename dateformat.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module"   but i have no type": "module  in package.json

Comment: I didn't realise you were trying to edit somebody else's code. Have you tried `import dateFormat from "dateformat"`?

Comment: I have added this now  and i get this error  
logger.js:13
import dateFormat from ('dateformat');
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I don't know what this means  apart from the import syntax is wrong  have i added it to the file wrong  import dateFormat from ('dateformat');